# GSON - Immutables vs Google

Tags: android, gson

I've noticed that the following GSON maven repository is the most popular for using this tool with Android projects:

```
compile 'org.immutables:gson:2.1.11'
```

My question is, why is this version of GSON so popular? When creating a new project should I use the one previously stated or the latest one from Google shown below? Are there any main differences?

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `org.immutables:gson` isn’t a full copy of Gson, it’s just an adapter that lets you use the `org.immutables` library with Google’s Gson.